# Dagger Component is not generated in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dagger-2

I am using Dagger2 for D.I but the problem is its  not generating component file for the interface. Below are my codes for module,gradle file and component.
I have done build / rebuild / clean / restart project.
What can be the cause for not generating Dagger Component  class ?

**Module Class**

```
    package com.global.Utills.DI

import com.global.Utills.SharedPref
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import javax.inject.Singleton


@Singleton
@Module
class NetworkModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideNetworkChecker() = SharedPref()

}
```

**SharedPref Class is Just a random class **

**Component Class**

```
    package com.global.Utills.DI

import android.content.Context
import com.global.Backend.NetworkApi
import com.global.Utills.DI.Module.RetrofitModule
import com.global.Utills.NetworkChecker
import com.global.Utills.SharedPref
import dagger.Component
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import javax.inject.Singleton


@Singleton
//@Component(modules = [ContextModule::class,RetrofitModule::class,NetworkModule::class])
@Component(modules = [NetworkModule::class])
interface Component {

//     fun getNetworkApi():NetworkApi
//
//    // fun getNetworkChecker():NetworkChecker
//
//     fun getContext():Context
     fun getShred():SharedPref
}
```

**Build.Gradle**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        applicationId "com.global.cvcv"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    kapt {
        generateStubs = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    //material design
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'

    // dimen.xml
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'

    //rxjava
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.5'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'

    // Lifecyles, LiveData and ViewModel
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    kapt 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.2.0'

    // Room
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.1.1"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"

    //DAGGER
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.22.1"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.22.1"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.22.1"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.22.1"



    //Firebase messaging dependency  firestore

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.5.0'

    //Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.1'
    implementation "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0"

    //Glide Library
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'



}
```

Comment: are there any error/warning logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Modules` cannot be scoped. Only methods can be scoped. Remove `@Singleton` from `NetworkModule`.

```
@Module
class NetworkModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideNetworkChecker() = SharedPref()
}
```